# Editing a table with perl ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, unix, cgi

I am in the middle of a perl script where basically I am reading data from a xls file and showing it in the page as an input text. The idea is that, once a user selects edit option from a menu, it will show the entire table which is fetched from a xls file and show the existing value in a text box.

Now, when a user edits the cells and clicks on save, I am able to send all the ids to a perl function. My problem is that I am not able to map the cells.

Eg: If a user enters a new value A for column1 row 1 and another Value B for column 2 and row 1 and then saves it, then is there a way to tell my perl function that new value A belongs to Column1 row1 and new value B belongs to Column2 row 1. Something similar to sending a 2d array to a perl subroutine from a submit button in ajax.

Comment: Show your ajax and cgi script?

Comment: I'd consider re-working this using: https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools but obviously, I don't know exactly what you're doing. I used to do workarounds with generated names for the cells fields etc. but this may be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Include the row and col inside the name of the control. Then you can use the following or the JavaScript equivalent:

```
my ($row, $col) = $param_name =~ /^cell([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)\z/
   or die;
```